# Accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

**Accumulation point:**

Let $ \tau$ be a topological on $ ‎\mathbb{N}‎ $‎‎ such that is generated by  $\{1,2\}, \{3,4\},\{5,6\}.... $.
Let $A$ be non-empty of $ ‎\mathbb{N}‎ $‎‎ and $ n_{0} \in A$.
If $ n_{0} $ is add, $ n_{0} + 1 $ will be a accumulation of $A$.
If $ n_{0} $ is even, $ n_{0} - 1 $ will be a accumulation of $A$. so in any way $A$ has a accumulation point.Then $ ( \mathbb{N}‎,\tau)$ is countably compact, but is not compact.

**(1) Why If $ n_{0} $ is even, $ n_{0} - 1 $ will be a accumulation of $A$?**

**(2) Why $ ( \mathbb{N}‎,\tau)$ is countably compact, but is not compact?**

Comment: So, the collection {1,2},{3,4}, etc. are the open sets? I thought it could be a basis, but the sets are pairwise-disjoint, so the unions of finite intersections will be empty.

Comment: @FBD Since finite intersections are empty, then this *is* a basis.

Comment: But don'we then have that these sets do not generate anything, since then all unions of finite intersections are then also empty? Doesn't this imply these are the open sets, given any union of finite intersectiobns is empty?

Answer (score 1):

To answer $1$, note that $n_0$ and $n_0 - 1$ are indistinguishable, so every open neighborhood about $n_0$ must contain $n_0 - 1$.

$2$ is wrong.  The collection of sets you have given, $\{ \{ n , n+1 \} : n \text{ is odd } \}$, is a countable open cover of $\mathbb N$ with no finite subcover (since if it did, then $\mathbb N$ would be finite).

Comment: You said that "$ n_{o} $ and $ n_{0} - 1 $ are indistinguishable, but every open neighborhood about $n_{ 0}$ must contain $n_{ 0} −1$ . " can you give me more explain?

Comment: @Maryam Let $n_0$ be even and let $U$ be an open set about $n_0$.  Then write $U = \bigcup_i B_i$ where $\{ B_i \}$ is a collection of basis elements in the basis you have given us.  So $\{ n_0 , n_0 - 1 \} \subset U$ since that is the only open set containing $n_0$ in the basis.